# New OpenCart e-commerce website: Responsive design vs Mobile theme

Tags: e-commerce, responsive-design, opencart

I'm starting a new e-commerce website based on [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/). The client wants the website to be functional and pretty in mobile devices. I have two options: I can either go with a responsive template; or, I can go with a [mobile theme](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=%20mobile%20theme). This is going to be a major furniture store shop, and I just wanted to see what your experiences are with designing mobile versions for your big ecommerce websites. What are the best practices? Is going with a responsive design something feasible when you have a big website?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer the mobile theme route, as it provides you with greater control over what gets downloaded by the customer, meaning you can save their bandwidth and increase site speed which is crucial in an e-commerce store. One mobile/table extension available (commercial) is the Omtex one which has proven to be very popular